# use implementation type in interface in java

Tags: java, generics, interface

I want to make an interface that forces each class that implements it to have a certain functionality, for the implemented class' type.

So say I have classes MyClassA, MyClassB, MyClassC, etc. that all need a function on their own type:

in MyClassA:

```
public class MyClassA implements MyClass {
    MyClassA function(MyClassA x) {
        doSomethingImplementedInMyClassA(x);
    }
}
```

in MyClassB:

```
public class MyClassB implements MyClass {
    MyClassB function(MyClassB x) {
        doSomethingImplementedInMyClassB(x);
    }
}
```

The question is, how to write the interface `MyClass` to require such function?

```
public interface MyClass {
    MyClass function(MyClass x);
}
```

obviously doesn't work, since the returning type is MyClass and not its implementation. How to do this properly in Java?

Comment: Any reason you couldn't add `doSomethingImplementedInMyClass()` to the interface?

Comment: I'm not sure how this would help?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by making an "interface that forces each class that implements it to have a certain functionality, for the implemented class' type"? How you are trying solve the problem may not be possible but alternatives should exist.

Comment: I'm trying to make several new types of numbers (well, actually "group elements" if you know some mathematics), and I would like to implement a.multiplyBy(b); and similar methods. So I would make an interface `GroupElement` and require each implementation of `GroupElement` to define a multiplication routine as `ImplementationOfGroupElement multiplyBy(ImplementationOfGroupElement b) {...}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use generics:

```
public interface MyClass<V extends MyClass<V>> {
    V function(V x);
}

public class MyClassA implements MyClass<MyClassA>
```

This is called the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

---

This is not perfect; it would still allow things like

```
public class MyClassB implements MyClass<MyClassA>
```

To do this correctly, you need higher-kinded types <sup>[citation needed]</sup>, which Java does not support.

Comment: Aha, using a class as its own generic, that's smart! Thanks!

Comment: @user1111929: BTW, you mean "as its own generic _parameter_".

Comment: This is a C++ idiom so its totally irrelevant to the question, Java has functionality for this. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the implementation always calls a method on the argument, why not just add that method to the interface?

```
interface MyClass {
    MyClass doSomething();
}

class MyClassA implements MyClass {
    MyClassA doSomething() {
        //implementation here
    }
}

class MyClassB implements MyClass {
    MyClassB doSomething() {
        //implementation here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do what you want to do in Java is like this:

1st you define your interface containing a *abstract method*, that is a method that is not defined yet.
Remind that an interface is not a class!

```
public interface Animal {
    public Animal reproduceWith(Animal someAnimal);
}
```

Then you define the classes that implements the interface and you override the abstract method but now you implement it with the code of your choice. That way the only thing that is the same in the class is the method name.
This effectively forces a class to implement a certain method.

```
public class Dog implements Animal {

    @Override
    public Animal reproduceWith(Animal someAnimal) {
        return new Dog();
    }
}


public class Cat implements Animal {

    @Override
    public Animal reproduceWith(Animal someAnimal) {
        return new Cat();
    }
}
```

After that you could for example make a list of *MyInterface* and iterate over it calling the same method even if its a different class.

```
List<Animal> list = new ArrayList<Animal>();
list.add(new Cat());
list.add(new Dog());

Animal cat = new Cat();
Animal dog = new Dog();

for (Animal animal : list) {
    System.out.println(animal.reproduceWith(cat));
    System.out.println(animal.reproduceWith(dog));
}
```

I hope that helps you out.

Comment: I don't really see how this relates to the question... What should I do to obtain the effect of `a.doSomething(b);` in your code?

Comment: public MyInterface myAbstractMethod(); in the interface 
and in the class you implement it. I will edit the answer.

Comment: I still don't see how that does `a.doSomething(b);`. What would be `a` and what would be `b` in your code?

Comment: a would be MyClassA and b would be MyClassB. So you can call the method of the interface and giving it an interface as parameter but the class can be different. The trick is that you know the method is the same so you can call it without having to check the type. I edited my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Your question was: how to force implementation of certain functionality in a class that implements an interface in Java. This is exactly what you asked for because that is exactly what an interface in Java does, it forces you to override the abstract method it defines. :) And there is no generics needed for this.

Comment: Aah, yes, I see what you mean. You are right, it *is* possible without generics! Although it is not very practical: it requires much longer code than just the intuitive a.doSomething(b) that the generics method offers, so I guess I will use generics anyway. But thanks for the input!

Comment: You're welcome but this offers you the same possibility ;) Basically your generic type in this case is the interface itself. 
MyInterface a = new MyClassA(); 
MyInterface b = new MyClassB(); 
a.doSomething(b);

Comment: Agreed, I expressed myself wrongly. I meant that MyInterface.doSomething() would need a much more complicated implementation: an if-else for every class implementing MyInterface, and this for every routine in MyInterface. Given that The fact I'll have about 30 different implementations of MyInterface would make this approach produce quite long code, and probably also slower code because of the many cases that have to be split. Not to mention the trouble that start when one routine has to repetitively call another, which would (if I understand you correctly) require a class-analysis every time.

Comment: There is no typecasting needed for different implementations of the same interface. So basically you dont need any if else. You should really try this out how it works. You can have 30 different implementations of MyInterface and you can call its methods instantly without having to find out what type it is.
An interface in Java is generic without generics :)

Comment: I see. You are quickly eliminating my concerns. Three more concerns: 1) Wouldn't the required typecasting within getMyClass (when replacing it with a function contents that requires internal parameters of aORb) cause some slowdown when calling this repeatedly in a long loop? Or is this happening internally anyway when using generics? 2) Another advantage of the CRTP approach is that it can reduce the number of generics. `MyClassA implements MyInterface<MyClassA,generic1,generic2,...,genericN>` allows you one clean name, while your approach would force the use of [too long, see next post]

Comment: `MyInterface<generic1,generic2,...,genericN>` everywhere, e.g. `public MyInterface<generic1,generic2,...,genericN> getMyClass(MyInterface<generic1,generic2,...,genericN> aORb)`. Do you happen to have any solutions for this in your approach? As this is a very handy functionality. 3) for some problems our intuition wants rather the opposite of your example, i.e. exactly not being able to have such a flexible interaction. `Horse x; sheep.reproduceWith(x)` should be dectected on IDE level as an error. I don't expect it possible (and no big deal), but one never knows what clever tricks you know. :)

Comment: (where Sheep and Horse both implement interface Animal which requires a `.reproduceWith(...)` funcion)

Comment: This does not have the intended semantics - `dog.reproduceWith(cat)` should not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably need is a parent class apart from an interface.

I find an interface is ideally used to define behavior thus `GroupElementA` **is a** `GroupElement` sounds conceptually more accurate rather than `GroupElementA` **behaves like a** `GroupElement`.

I would consider using a parent class to achieve what you want to have.

```
/**
 * An abstract group element.
 */
abstract class GroupElement
{
    // attributes of all group elements
}

/**
 * Defines behavior for objects that can be multiplied with
 * GroupElements.
 */
interface GroupElementMultipliable
{
    public GroupElement multiplyBy(GroupElement groupElement);
}

/**
 * Defines behavior for objects that can be divided by
 * GroupElements.
 */
interface GroupElementDivisible
{
    public GroupElement divideBy(GroupElement groupElement);
}

/**
 * An abstract GroupElement that can perform operations like
 * multiplication and division.
 *
 * Then again this class may not be necessary. The interfaces
 * implemented here may actually be directly implemented by
 * GroupElementA. GroupElementA will also be the one to inherit
 * GroupElement.
 */
abstract class OperableGroupElement extends GroupElement
        implements GroupElementMultipliable, GroupElementDivisible
{
    // attributes of all operable group elements
}

/**
 * A concrete GroupElement that can perform operations like
 * multiplication and division.
 */
class GroupElementA extends OperableGroupElement
{
    @Override
    public GroupElementA multiplyBy(GroupElement groupElement)
    {
        // Since we expect to multiply with another GroupElementA
        // we attempt to typcast the groupElement
        GroupElementA groupElementA = (GroupElementA) groupElement;

        // do multiplication operation -- this * groupElementA
        // then return new self
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public GroupElementA divideBy(GroupElement groupElement)
    {
        // Since we expect to divide by another GroupElementA
        // we attempt to typcast the groupElement
        GroupElementA groupElementA = (GroupElementA) groupElement;

        // do division operation -- this / groupElementA
        // then return new self
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach. However, if the typecasting is required, it is then still faster than the generic parameter approach suggested by SLaks? It certainly doesn't produce shorter code. What would be the benefits of your approach exactly? I tend to use Interfaces whenever possible, since they don't give an inheritance slowdown (which even abstract classes do, iirc).

Comment: Hi @user1111929, glad you found this interesting. Actually, this was also the first time I learned about CRTP (thanks to SLaks) so I can't really compare my approach. Yes it does take up more LOC but it is a nice OO solution, AFAIK. I'm not really a performance junkie but I've also read around regarding performance and the only major concern seems to be the typecasting.