# java interface method input itself

Tags: java, methods, types, parameters, interface

I have an interface that has a method that takes in itself, such as

```
public interface Vehicle {
  void bump(Vehicle other);
}
```

Now, I want to implement this interface in such a way that a Vehicle will only bump into Vehicles of its own type. That is, I want something such as

```
public class BumperCar implements Vehicle {
  public void bump(BumperCar other){
    System.out.println("They bounce off harmlessly and continue going.")
  }
}

public class Train implements Vehicle {
  public void bump(Train other){
    System.out.println("Breaking news: Dozens die in horrible train on train collision.")
  }
}
```

But bumps between BumperCars and Trains do nothing, even though both classes must implement bump(Vehicle). What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use implementation type in interface in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232945/use-implementation-type-in-interface-in-java)

Comment: You are not overriding the method. It has a different signature.

Comment: Do you or don't you want different types of vehicles to bumb between themselves.? Besides, add the code where you actually make them bump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite happy with solutions mentioned in the 'possible duplicate comment' so I will show how I would do it.

First, as I said in the comment, you are not overriding the method from the interface. The signatures need to match.

In order to get this right, create a function with the signature from the interface. And in the method use the `instanceof` operator to check if your object is from the correct type. Like this:

```
public class BumperCar implements Vehicle {
  public void bump(Vehicle other){
    if(other instanceof BumperCar) {
        System.out.println("...");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree, I'm not satisfied with those answers. This is the way that I'm going to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since Java lacks the possibility to use the `self` type in classes, a generic construct called "simulated self-type" is typically used for this:

```
abstract class Vehicle<T extends Vehicle<T>> {
    public abstract void bump(T other);
}

public class Car extends Vehicle<Car> {
        @Override public void bump(Car other) {}
}
```

The only caveat is that one has always to specify the type in the class declaration.

In core Java libraries, an example of the simulated self-type usage is the [Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) class.

Comment: This is a great answer, and I would probably use it in a setting where I have less control over my code and how it's used since this would force types better. But since it's my code and I'm more positive about passing in the correct types, I'll use Lars' answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use self referencing generic type:

```
    public interface Vehicle< T extends Vehicle<T> > {
        void bump(T other);
    }

    public class BumperCar implements Vehicle<BumperCar> {

        public void bump(BumperCar other){
        }
   }

    public class Train  implements Vehicle<Train > {

        public void bump(Train  other){
        }
   }
```